# Installing mypysql

Tags: python, mysql

In the readme file for [mypysql](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mypysql/), under the Installation section, all that is written is the following:

```
$ svn export http://mypysql.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mypysql mypysql
$ cd mypysql
$ make compile
$ sudo make install
```

Where would I execute such code?

Comment: "Since version 0.4.0, mypysql is now more or less PEP249 compliant." ... This does not inspire confidence...

Answer (score 1):

At a shell prompt.

Comment: I tried that, but it says that `$` is not recognised. So I typed it without `$` but `svn` isn't recognised either.

Comment: The `$` represents the shell prompt. And you may need to install `subversion`.

Comment: Okay, I got it going up to `make compile`. But alas, `make` isn't recognised!

Comment: Then you'll need to install `make` or `gmake`.

Answer (score 0):

I have compile mypysql-0.5 for window using vc2005. The project src at  [mypysql-0.5-win.zip](http://211.147.215.55/down/mypysql-0.5-win.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing it, you're compiling it. To install it you just need to copy mypysql.pyd and libmysql.dll to [your python folder]/DLLs/

You'll need to get libmysql.dll from your mysql folder or download it from the mysql website.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the above code at the command prompt.

If you are using Windows OS then execute it at C:\

If you are using Mac/Unix/Linux like OS, start the terminal and execute it there - []$

You will need to have the administrator privileges to do this.